# (Terraform, Cloud Run) Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to run a docker image on **Cloud Run** with the **Terraform** code below:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-214771"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "hello-world"
  location = "asia-northeast1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/myproject-214771/hello-world:latest"
      }
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
}
```

Then, it was successful to run the docker image:

[image]

But when I access the URL, it shows this:

[image]

> Error: Forbidden Your client does not have permission to get URL /
> from this server

Are there any mistakes in my **Terraform** code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add(Copy & paste) this code below to your **Terraform** code **to allow unauthenticated invocations for public API or website**:

```js
data "google_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/run.invoker"
    members = [
      "allUsers",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  location    = google_cloud_run_service.default.location
  project     = google_cloud_run_service.default.project
  service     = google_cloud_run_service.default.name

  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.noauth.policy_data
}
```

So this is **the full code**:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-214771"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
  name     = "hello-world"
  location = "asia-northeast1"

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/myproject-214771/hello-world:latest"
      }
    }
  }

  traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
  }
}

data "google_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/run.invoker"
    members = [
      "allUsers",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "noauth" {
  location    = google_cloud_run_service.default.location
  project     = google_cloud_run_service.default.project
  service     = google_cloud_run_service.default.name

  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.noauth.policy_data
}
```

Finally, your URL shows your website properly:

[image]

Moreover, now **"Authentication"** is **"Allow unauthenticated"**:

[image]

Don't forget to add the role **"Cloud Run Admin"** to your **service account**:

[image]

Otherwise, you cannot **allow unauthenticated invocations for public API or website** then you will get this error below:

> Error setting IAM policy for cloudrun service
> "v1/projects/myproject-214771/locations/asia-northeast1/services/hello-world":
> googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'run.services.setIamPolicy' denied on
> resource
> 'projects/myproject-214771/locations/asia-northeast1/services/hello-world'
> (or resource may not exist).

Moreover, with these roles below, you cannot **allow unauthenticated invocations for public API or website**:

[image]

Only the role **"Cloud Run Admin"** can **allow unauthenticated invocations for public API or website**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

most likely you need to give the service account "Cloud Run Admin" access, it needs run.services.setIamPolicy permission to change the settings on the new cloud run

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33324373)